# React-dropzone style drop area

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dropzone.js

I am new to `reactjs`,
trying to create a component that uses [react-dropzone](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone). 
I was wondering, what is the best way to override the default setting to style the drop area.

So far I have `inline style`, but it looks to me that I am not doing the 'right' thing.

```
<Row>
    <Jumbotron className="text-center">
        <h4>Create a manual call</h4>
        <Dropzone 
            className=""
            multiple={false}
            onDrop={this.onDrop}
            style={{"width" : "100%", "height" : "20%", "border" : "1px solid black"}}>
                <div>
                    Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.
                </div>
        </Dropzone>
    </Jumbotron>
</Row>
```

Any help or better suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: How does it look in the end? any error in console?

Comment: @Manoz no no it's working fine, I was just wondering if I am doing it the 'right' way. I am new to the framework and I don't want to pick up bad habits from the get go

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you are doing is totally fine. If you would prefer you can write your styling in a .css file that you add to your project. Give the component a className and import the css somewhere in your project.

```
<Dropzone
  className="dropzone"
  multiple={false}
  onDrop={this.onDrop}>
  <div>
    Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.
  </div>
</Dropzone>

/* styles.css */
.dropzone {
  width : 100%;
  height : 20%;
  border : 1px solid black;
}
```

There are more involved libraries to do css-in-js like styled-components, but there is no 100% correct solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a style object like this

```
const dropzoneStyle = {
    width  : "100%",
    height : "20%",
    border : "1px solid black"
};
```

Use the variable in jsx like this

```
<Dropzone 
  className=""
  multiple={false}
  onDrop={this.onDrop}
  style={dropzoneStyle}
>
  <div>
       Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.
  </div>
</Dropzone>
```